# the image's black when I resize image with pygame.transform,resize() in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm using pygame.transform.scale() to resize the image but when I do it, the image turns to all black. I tried to use pygame.transform.smoothscale(), pygame.transform.rotozoom().

or is there a way to make the size of image grow a little by little?

here's my code

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()  # 초기화

animation_update_speed = 36  # Frame 설정

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)  # pygame 창 설정

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# 오브젝트 설정

# 공 이미지 1 설정:
ball_1_x = 400
ball_1_y = 400

# 폭.발 파티클 설정:
boom_particle_x = ball_1_x - 125
boom_particle_y = ball_1_y + 125
explosion = pygame.image.load("explosion_image.jpg")
explosion_2 = pygame.transform.scale(screen, (265, 265))


boom = pygame.mixer.Sound("new_clear_explosion.wav")

screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
pygame.display.update()
screen.blit(explosion, (boom_particle_x, boom_particle_y))
pygame.display.update()
pygame.time.delay(animation_update_speed)

screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
pygame.display.update()
screen.blit(explosion_2, (boom_particle_x - 15, boom_particle_y))
pygame.display.update()
pygame.time.delay(animation_update_speed)
```

Comment: The only thing you're scaling in this code is the screen itself (which doesn't have anything drawn on it yet), *not* the explosion image you just loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line 21 you write

```
explosion = pygame.image.load("explosion_image.jpg")
```

However, line 22 writes

```
explosion_2 = pygame.transform.scale(screen, (265, 265))
```

This means that you are loading the image into explosion and then in pygame.transform.scale() you write that the surface that you are resizing is screen and not explosion.

If you would like to resize that explosion image then you must write

```
explosion_2 = pygame.transform.scale(explosion, (265, 265))
```

As seen on the Pygame docs (linked below), the first parameter into the pygame.transform.scale() function is the surface that you wish to resize, not the screen itself.

Link: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.scale